# Java Slick2D Line Constructor throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, slick2d

In Java Slick2D, I am attempting to make a line using a constructor that takes two float arrays, as detailed here: http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Line.html

My code is the following:

```
float[] floatArray1 = { 10.0f, 155.0f };
float[] floatArray2 = { 20.0f, 165.0f };
Line line1 = new Line ( floatArray1, floatArray2 );
```

However, this third line (line 263 in my code) throws a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.newdawn.slick.geom.Line.set(Line.java:217)
    at org.newdawn.slick.geom.Line.set(Line.java:138)
    at org.newdawn.slick.geom.Line.<init>(Line.java:112)
    at view.play.Character.checkIntersectionMovementVector(Character.java:263) (my method)
```

Why is this happening?

Edit: It is worth noting that using its constructor that takes four float values instead of two float arrays of length two works, and throws no exception:

```
        Line line = new Line ( 10.0f, 155.0f, 20.0f, 165.0f );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the `Line` class. The `Line.set()` method that is eventually called is this:

```
public void set(float sx, float sy, float ex, float ey) {
    super.pointsDirty = true;
    start.set(sx, sy);     // this is line 217
    end.set(ex, ey);
    float dx = (ex - sx);
    float dy = (ey - sy);
    vec.set(dx,dy);

    lenSquared = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
}
```

However, the `start` instance variable of the `Line` class isn't initialized in the constructor you call:

```
public Line(float[] start, float[] end) {
    super();

    set(start, end);  // line 112
}
```

You should report the bug to the Slick2d maintainers. As a workaround, you should be able to use the `Vector2f` input constructor:

```
public Line(Vector2f start, Vector2f end)
```

As the `set()` method used here *does* initialize `start`:

```
public void set(Vector2f start, Vector2f end) {
    super.pointsDirty = true;
    if (this.start == null) {
        this.start = new Vector2f();
    }
    this.start.set(start);

    if (this.end == null) {
        this.end = new Vector2f();
    }
    this.end.set(end);

    vec = new Vector2f(end);
    vec.sub(start);

    lenSquared = vec.lengthSquared();
}
```

The four float input constructor also works because it calls the `Vector2f` constructor above:

```
public Line(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    this(new Vector2f(x1, y1), new Vector2f(x2, y2));
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you. I will look into informing them, if I can work out how.

Comment: @AlexW brilliant answer that doesn't merit an upvote? Jeez, tough crowd.

Comment: I do not meet the sufficient reputation to upvote, I am (or at least was) on 10 reputation and an upvote requires 15. Otherwise I would indeed give you an upvote. I did try just in case, and alas was rejected. As this is the case, I hoped the best answer tick and my clear appreciation would have been sufficient.

Comment: When I get to 15 reputation, you may have your upvote.